# WebView2 automatically close alert after user responds

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, webview2

I have an a WebView2 in Windows Forms. One of the links within the webpage is:

```
<a href="search-ms:crumb=&amp;crumb=location:C:%5CUsers" title="" target="_blank" class="img-Lazy-warp">Open Users</a>
```

This causes a window to open:
[image]

When the user clicks on 'Open Windows Explorer' the window 'Untiled - about:blank' remains open.

Is there a way to close it?

Comment: What is that `href` supposed to do?

Comment: You have `target="_blank"` that will open a new window (and keep the old one open).

Comment: @PoulBak you are right. I missed this. You can write it as an answer and I will accept it.